# i cant change a text value when using dropdown menu - flutter

Tags: flutter

i'm pretty much new at flutter , and recently i started to work with PopupMenuButton which i'm using to allow the user to select which language they wish to use and then renders the selected language in a container (using it as it to make it look like a textfield dropdown menu) ,

so basically when the user selects the language the selectedlanguage value actually do change and the app's language also changes but the text inside the container never changes

```
import 'package:Terzi/main.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Testable extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestableState createState() => _TestableState();
}

class _TestableState extends State<Testable> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final TextEditingController _controller = new TextEditingController();
    var languages = ['English','اللغة العربية','Türkçe'];
    String slectedLanguage="English";
    return  new Scaffold(

        body: new Center(
          child: new Container(
            child: new Column(
              children: [
                new Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
                  child: new Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.blue

                            ),
                            height: 65, width: double.infinity,
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: Text(slectedLanguage,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 16),),
                          ),
                      ),
                      new PopupMenuButton<String>(
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                        onSelected: (String value) {
                          setState(() {
                            slectedLanguage= value;
                            switch( slectedLanguage)
                            {
                              case "English" :
                                MyApp.setLocale(context, Locale('en','US'));
                                break;
                              case "اللغة العربية" :
                                MyApp.setLocale(context, Locale('ar','SA'));
                                break;
                              case "Türkçe" :
                                MyApp.setLocale(context, Locale('tr','TR'));
                                break;
                            }
                            print(slectedLanguage);
                          });

                        },
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                          return languages.map<PopupMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                            return new PopupMenuItem(child: new Text(value), value: value);
                          }).toList();
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `selectedLanguage` will always be `'English'` because it is a local variable initialized at the beginning of your `build` method. Instead, initialize `selectedLanguage` as an instance variable of your State class `_TestableState`:

```
class Testable extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestableState createState() => _TestableState();
}

class _TestableState extends State<Testable> {
  String selectedLanguage = 'English';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final TextEditingController _controller = new TextEditingController();
    var languages = ['English', 'اللغة العربية', 'Türkçe'];
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Center(
        child: new Container(
          child: new Column(
            children: [
              new Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
                child: new Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue),
                        height: 65,
                        width: double.infinity,
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Text(
                          selectedLanguage,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    new PopupMenuButton<String>(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                      onSelected: (String value) {
                        setState(() {
                          selectedLanguage = value;
                          switch (selectedLanguage) {
                            case "English":
                              MyApp.setLocale(context, Locale('en', 'US'));
                              break;
                            case "اللغة العربية":
                              MyApp.setLocale(context, Locale('ar', 'SA'));
                              break;
                            case "Türkçe":
                              MyApp.setLocale(context, Locale('tr', 'TR'));
                              break;
                          }
                          print(selectedLanguage);
                        });
                      },
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return languages
                            .map<PopupMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                          return new PopupMenuItem(
                              child: new Text(value), value: value);
                        }).toList();
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```